phpfpm and apache configuration not working
i'm recently working on 3-tier architecture on ubuntu virtual machines , 1 desktop and 2 servers,

Their network configuration is set to bridged Adapter in order to communicate with the wifi card directly




Machine
Role




Ubuntu Desktop 22.04
Apache 2.4.52


Ubuntu Server 1 22.04
PHP-FPM 8.1


Ubuntu Server 2  22.04
MySQL 8.0.36




First i've enabled proxy,proxy_fcgi and rewrite modules because apache and phpfpm communicate using fastcgi protcol , configured my apache virtual host and set sethandler ip to phpFPM_serverIP:port(9000) ,reloaded the apache2 service and checked the service and it works fine

My Virtual Host Configuration
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sghaierDev.com
ServerAlias www.sghaierDev.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
# PHP-FPM proxying
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php_fpm_server_ip:9000"
</FilesMatch>

DocumentRoot /var/www/sghaierDev
<Directory /var/www/sghaierDev>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


After that i passed to phpfpm server where i set the listen directive in configuration file (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf) ,restarted the service and it runs perfectly

php fpm configuration (ommited the comments to clarify)
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = php_fpm_server_ip:9000
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3


same steps for mysql where i set the bind-address to mysqlserverIp restarted the service and it works fine also

Mysql configuration (ommited the comments to clarify)
user        = mysql
port        = 3306
datadir     = /mnt/mysql_data
bind-address        = mysql_server_ip
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Test phase

while testing without the filesMatch directive ,the access to a php file such as types.php is fine


types.php code

<?php
$user = "adem";
$password = "password";
$database = "projects";
$table = "categories";

try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql_server_ip;dbname=$database", 
  $user, $password);
  echo "<h2>Projects categories</h2><ol>";
  foreach($db->query("SELECT p_type FROM $table") as $row) {
    echo "<li>" . $row['p_type'] . "</li>";
}
  echo "</ol>";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

Problem

when adding the mentionned directive in order to set the connection between phpfpm and apache ,he returns file not found , i tought maybe i should change the file permissions which what i have done but i get the same output , i've also checked the configuration files in both phpfpm and apache machines (especially the ip addresses) and the values are well-set ,also chekced the firewall permissions on both sides and they allow from any host with port 9000(phpfpm) and 80(apache)
also i,ve checked the error log mentionned in the virtual host and it shows this error


[Mon Apr 01 16:41:36.755830 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 5356] [client php-fpm_ip:49204] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'


Any Solutions guys cuz i'm a newbie to handling these type of architectures and i wasted too many time in searching for a solution , and thanks in advance

Did you try rebooting?

@Subash rebooted many times but still the same
